# Java arrays question

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing a program for a homework assignment in Java in an arrays chapter.  Before I do my question I'll go ahead and post the directions here to avoid confusion.

> This program is model after The
>   International Gymnastics Federation
>   using a scoring system for men’s  and
>   women’s artistic gymnastics. The
>   system incorporates credit for the
>   routines difficulty and  execution.
>   The Execution and Difficulty Score is
>   calculated by averaging the middle
>   three of five scores.  The Execution
>   and Difficulty Score after average are
>   added together for final score.  The
>   Execution and  Difficulty score are
>   between 0-5. This program will print
>   out direction for program and title. 
>   The program should intake 5 judges
>   score for Execution and Difficulty. 
>   You will need to use a for loop to
>   intake 5 judges score, and do until
>   scores are  within range.  Remember
>   you have Execution and Difficulty
>   scores that must be within range.  If
>   the user  enters Execution score
>   wrong, they must reenter score again
>   and came not continue until score is 
>   corrected.  The same will be true for
>   Difficulty score.  Use the BubbleSort
>   to sort scores for Execution  and
>   Difficulty. Them use a print() method
>   to print results. One of the last
>   steps in the program is to  calculate
>   average of middle three scores for
>   both Execution and Difficulty and
>   print out the Overall Total  Score, by
>   adding the average of the scores.

So my question is can I take in array variables through user input?  I am doing this for the judge which I have made an array of.  Not sure if this is right but here is my code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CH6PA
{
    private double difficulty;
    private int score;
    private double[] average;
public CH6PA
{
    public static main void(String[]args)
    {
        int[] judge;
        judge = new int[5];
        judge[0]=keyboard.nextInt();
        judge[1]=keyboard.nextInt();
        judge[2]=keyboard.nextInt();
        judge[3]=keyboard.nextInt();
        judge[4]=keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter the difficulty score for each judge (0-5)");
        judge[0] = keyboard.nextInt();
```

From making the array I am going on and accepting the difficulty score from each judge but am not sure how to do that.  Where I have judge[0]=keyboard.nextInt();  is that the correct way to get the score of the first judge?

Comment: What happens when you try to compile and run this? Does it work? If not, what goes wrong? If you don't know how to tell whether it works or not, what might you add to the program so you could confirm that? (Also, do you have an interactive debugger?)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the input is.  Have the user press enter after each score, then yes, you are doing it correctly.  Otherwise, you have to specify what the delimiter is and use String.split or something similar to break it up.

There are a couple of things wrong with your code:

- I have to assume that `keyboard` is a Scanner. I don't see it declared anywhere.
- The `public CH6PA` looks out of place and is probably a type-o

As for your line: `judge[0]=keyboard.nextInt()`, that looks fine.

Good luck with your homework and I hope you enjoy programming!!

EDIT: I think you know this, but your code won't compile as-is.  You don't have a closing brace, but that's just nit-picky.

Comment: I have changed a lot of things and found a bunch of errors.  Right now it compiles at least.  I'll probably have to add a new question up soon but I may be able to figure it out.  Thanks.